# Outlook Address Book Search (No Looping?)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Is there anyway to search Outlook address box for a contact using their email address without any sort of For Loops? There are so many contacts in our Global Contact List and it takes forever to go through the list. Is there no search or find function that can be applied to the contact list.

**I am looking to get information like the phone # and office for the user if they are found in the contact list.**

All the solutions that I have found involve looping through the contact list.
[http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=76588](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869721.aspx)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869721.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve` to resolve the name (or address) in the address book. Even if you pass an SMTP address, it will be resolved to a GAL user (if there is a match).

Comment: Dmitry, I guess I missed placing this in the original question. I have the user's email, and I want to find it in the address book. Then get information such as the phone # and office (updated the main post). Not sure if I can extract information besides the name for outlook.recipient.

Comment: Of course you can - use Recipient.AddressEntry. From there you can use either AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser or AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty to read any MAPI property (use OutlookSpy to see what is available).

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome. This should work for what I need. Will post the code once I am done with it.

Comment: Thanks again Dmitry. Posted a macro to do the search for the contact phone # as a separate answer as I could not place code in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that I am using to get the phone # of a contact using the email address from the global address book - using Dmitry Streblechenko approach.

```
Sub GetPhone(EmailAddress As String) 'Gets the phone # for contact
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim OutRecipients As Outlook.Recipient
Dim PhoNe As String


On Error Resume Next
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Set OutRecipients = OutMail.Recipients.Add(EmailAddress)
OutRecipients.Resolve

PhoNe = OutRecipients.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.BusinessTelephoneNumber
Set OutRecipients = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to create a dummy email. Use Namespace.CreateRecipient / Recipient.Resolve.

Comment: Tried using Namespace.CreateRecipient but ran into an error and I had no time to entertain it. I needed a functional macro real quick. I have used resolving recipients before with emails, so that is why I went that route. When I have a chance, I will try it again with Namespace.CreateRecipient.