# How to Pull Email Address from Global Address List in Outlook VBA if the Associated Name contains String

Tags: vba, list, outlook, global, assets

First time poster! I am trying to pull the email address from an entry in the Global Address List in Outlook to refer to within my VBA code. I need to input a project code, whereby the code will need to look through the GAL and find the entry where the project code is found in the name. When it finds this, I need it to return the associated email address (PrimarySMTPAddress). If no, I need it to say 'Project code not found'.

I am very new to VBA, so I can't put this thought into code. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you Google?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500724/outlook-address-book-search-no-looping
https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/export-exchange-gal-excel/

Comment: Hi, yes. That's not exactly what I need. For example, within the name in the GAL I have '0100 Project 1'. I need a code to scan for 0100 (after I input this via an input box) and find the associated email address for this name - i.e. look across the same row. I then need to assign (e.g.) ProjectEmail = Email Address.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method of the `Namespace` class which creates a `Recipient` object. This method is most commonly used to create a `Recipient` object for use with the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method, for example, to open a delegator's folder. It can also be used to verify a given name against an address book.

```
Sub ResolveName()
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Project Name 0001") 
 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```